# NSPopover closes automatically

Tags: cocoa, swift, nspopover

I have a xib with my view and an NSPopover with Transient behavior:

[image: IB nspopover setup]

In the view controller, I have an action to control the popover like this:

```
    @IBAction func moreClicked(sender: NSButton) {      
    if !moreOpen  {
        moreOpen = true
        scriptsPopover.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, ofView: sender, preferredEdge: 2)
    } else {
        moreOpen = false
        scriptsPopover.close()
    }
}
```

When I click my button the popover appears as expected. But after 5 seconds it disappears.

I want the popover to present a number of buttons and only disappear when the user clicks one of those buttons or clicks elsewhere in the UI. Like the Autolayout Pin button in Interface Builder to mention an example.

I tried defining the behavior as Transient, Semi-transient, Application-defined. All have exactly the same result: It dismisses itself after a few seconds.

I tried implementing the popoverShouldClose delegate and returning false to let me control it. It does block the close, but when the user clicks the button to close, it just opens a **new** popover on top of the old. The popover also loses its arrow after I return false from popoverShouldClose, which looks weird.

Here's a recording of the annoying automatic close

[image: NSpopover annnoyingly closes itself]

Comment: Is your `moreClicked()` method being called a second time? That would close the pop-over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the stack trace when the `popoverShouldClose` method is called. You'll see the cause of this in that stack trace, and from there, try to eliminate this cause.

What I'm suspecting is that your popover is being deallocated as it isn't being strongly held by you.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm holding it strongly (tried both removing weak and IBOutlet). The calls just before the delegate are refreshing a tableView which actually does some relatively heavy stuff like instantiating a few viewcontrollers. 

I tried reproducing the code in a new project and everything works fine there. Any ideas on how to tell cocoa to hold on to the popover?

Comment: wait a minute.. The viewcontroller I'm refreshing is the very viewcontroller that makes the popover disappear. Thanks!

Comment: Cool @MortenJ. Glad you got it sorted. I was facing a similar issue with UIPopover on iOS, so was pretty sure this was related :)